# How can I find non-linear regression model starting values?

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to fit a non-linear tree diameter height model (Max & Burkhart, 1976) to my data set (consists of D, breast height diameter (cm); H, total tree height (m); hi section height from ground level, di diameter at hi level etc.) in R.

I'm having trouble on fitting the model. I think it's because of the starting parameter values of the equation. I get "NaNs produced" errors. I tried to tweak the starting parameters. The number of errors decreased to 1 but not zero. So I need to find a way to estimate starting parameters for a non-linear regression model. I searched for Self starting models but could not apply to my equation because of complexity of the equation and my lack of knowledge. I will add all my data set here so you guys maybe show me a way.

By the way, I'm not sure if I can attach files to my question, so I will give a link to my dataset for anyone who wants to view or download. I uploaded my data to google drive and the link is 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q7W1bUcx4sK2G2QPte7ZtCudSLfBxpet/view?usp=sharing

```
# Function to compute Max & Burkhart (1976) equation
ComputeDi.MaxBurkhart <- function(hi, d, h, b1, b2, b3, b4, a1, a2){
    x <- hi / h
    x1 <- x - 1 
    x2 <- x ^ 2 - 1
    di <- d * sqrt(b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * (a1 - x) ^ 2 * ((a1 - x) >= 0.0) + b4 * (a2 - x) ^ 2 * ((a2 - x) >= 0.0))
    return(di)
}

# Set the working directory
setwd("../Data")

# Load data and rename some variables
sylvestris <- read.csv("mydata.csv")

# Global fitting
nlmod.fp.di <- nls(di ~ ComputeDi.MaxBurkhart(hi, d, h, b1, b2, b3, b4, a1, a2), data = sylvestris, start = c(b1 = -2.53, b2 = 1.2, b3 = -1.5, b4 = 22, a1 = 0.72, a2 = 0.15

), control = nls.control(tol = 1e-07))
summary(nlmod.fp.di, correlation = T)
```

It's all OK until here. I'm getting Nan Errors after here!

```
# Set seed and select names of trees
trees <- unique(sylvestris$tree) 
set.seed(15)
result.list <- list()
i <- 1
while(length(trees) > 0){
    tree.smp <- sample(trees, 10, replace = F)
    sylvestris.smp <- sylvestris[sylvestris$tree %in% tree.smp, ]
    fitting.ols <- try(nls(di ~ ComputeDi.MaxBurkhart(hi, d, h, b1, b2, b3, b4, a1, a2), data = sylvestris.smp, start = c(b1 = -2.53, b2 = 1.2, b3 = -1.5, b4 = 22, a1 = 0.72, a2 = 0.15

), control = nls.control(tol = 1e-07)), silent = T)
    if(class(fitting.ols)[1] == "try-error"){
            fit.smp <- data.frame(trees = paste(tree.smp, collapse = "_"), 
t(rep(NA, 8)))
            names(fit.smp) <- c("trees", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "a1", 
"a2", "NS", "RSE")
    } else {
            nlmod.ols <- fitting.ols
            fit.smp <- data.frame(trees = paste(tree.smp, collapse = "_"), t(coef(fitting.ols)), NS = sum(summary(fitting.ols)$parameters[, 4] > 0.05), RSE = summary(fitting.ols)$sigma)
    }
    result.list[[i]] <- fit.smp
    i <- i + 1
    trees <- trees[!trees %in% tree.smp]        
}
```

I expect significant parameter estimations without any NaN errors. I'm sure the problem is about the starting values because this code block works perfect with another data set. When I changed the data, I get this errors. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can provide sample data with `dput` as links to drive may not be accessible by all and/or may expire in the future.

Comment: The nls2 package provides a brute force method and other methods which can be used to to find starting values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the package [`nls.multstart`](https://github.com/padpadpadpad/nls.multstart), which is made to simplify the estimation of starting values.

You can basically specify ranges of starting parameters, and the regression will be made using the best parameters, based on [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) score.

Comment: Actually I tried to used nls.mutistart package, after seeing your comment. However, with the lack of my knowledge in R, I wasn't able to make it work. Can you please show me how to use it? I'm really sorry about my basic questions. But I'm a newbie in R and need some assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but I have never used it myself yet. From what I have seen, the function ǹls_multstart` is made to work just like the base `nls` function. Instead of specifying the starting values with the argument `start`, you can specify a broad range of values by specifying lower and upper bounds, respectively with `start_lower` and `start_upper`. I cannot help you more on that sorry.